# C# Confusion around List of object references seemingly not referring to the same object

Tags: c#, list, object, reference

I have a class which has some object fields and I then make a list out of those fields. But I'm confused about how many objects actually exist.
I think the `List` is a reference type so modifying an object from the list should also modify the field

But if I modify the List & set an item equal to a new object, it only changes the list, not the field

```
public class MyClass{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "Default value";
}


public class TestClass{
    private MyClass objectField = new MyClass();

    public void run(){
        List<MyClass> listOfObjects = new List<MyClass> { objectField };

        //Both objectField and listOfObjects[0] have the same value
        listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = "Changed value 1st time";

        //objectField is "Default value" and listOfObjects[0] is "Changed value 2nd time"
        listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = new MyClass();
        listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = "Changed value 2nd time";
    }

    public static void Main() {
        TestClass tester = new TestClass();
        tester.run();
    }
}
```

Why are there now seemingly 2 objects now? Did the `new` destroy the reference to the field?
**Is there a way to make the field still refer to the new object I create in the list?**

**This is a simply example, but I have a large list and don't want to have to go and manually update the fields to the values in the list**

```
listOfObjects[0] = new MyClass();
listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = "Changed value 2nd time";
objectField=listOfObjects[0];  //I want to avoid this
```

### Edit (Clarifications)

- The real scenario has many object fields of the same base class
- I wanted to do the same thing (change property values or instantiate new objects) to all my fields at once so I thought I could just put the fields in a `List`
- I still wanted to be able to refer to the object via it's field name, not just the `List` index but it appears it can't be done

Comment: Please tell us how you're observing that the "two objects" have different values. There really is only one object here so your observation is faulty.

Comment: Also, this code must be wrong on other counts as well, this line - `listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = new MyClass();` - surely won't compile, will it? The property type is `string`, you're trying to store a `MyClass` into it. You've also spelled the class name wrong two places, `MyCLass` with an uppercase `L`. **Please post the real code.**

Comment: What would you achieve by doing so? Why would you update object properties' values by adding them in the list?

Comment: @vendettamit I want to do the same thing to multiple objects so I put them in a list to just do the same thing to a bunch of objects at once

Comment: And you can certainly do so, but since you've posted broken code, for other reasons than what you're asking about, we can only guess and speculate about what the actual problem is. Please post your real code.

Comment: If you want help then take the time to post a minimal, complete example that actually runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Definition of a minimal, complete (and verifiable) example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go on a few assumptions here, as your code would not normally compile.  Anyways, a generic List<> in C#, when the generic type is a class (reference) type, is a collection of references to those classes, but not a direct pointer to a local object that you put into it.

So basically you have a bunch of class objects hanging out in memory and the list just has references to them.  As soon as you new up a new object and REPLACE at one of the indexes, you are replacing the reference to the object in the collection with the new object (not the object in memory itself).  The local field still has the reference to the old object.

```
//E.G.
var objectField = new MyClass();
var listOfObjects = new List<MyClass>{ bjectField };

// Here you are modifying the property of the original object
listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = "1st change";

// Here you are replacing the reference to that object with
//  with a reference to a new object, so the properties are totally fresh
//  properties go with the old object, a new object has all new fields / properties
//  and references
//  also, this does not replace the reference to your local field / property
listOfObjects[0] = new MyClass();

// here you are modifying the property on the new object, not the original
listOfObjects[0].MyProperty = "2nd change";
```

The field, or property belongs to that object.  A class in C# is not some structure that you can overlay with a new struct and assume that the fields / properties will just pick up the references to the old fields / properties.

Additionally, passing a local field into a collection does not mean you are giving it a pointer to that field, you are giving it a reference to that object.  Even in C++, you would have to specify that you were passing in a pointer to that particular field / property.  You cannot do "pointer magic" in C# like you can in C or C++ and change a pointer to a new object (well you *can* but then you have to do unsafe code, *don't do it unless you are interacting with native code structures*).

TL;DR; Passing a field into a collection does not mean you are passing a direct pointer to that field into the collection.  Therefore, replacing it in the collection does not change your local field.

Comment: Thanks
I guess it was all confusion about pointers vs references. Coming from C++,  I keep confusing myself